# In an array of randomly generated booleans, change 'k' falses to trues to create the largest continuous chain of trues

Tags: algorithm

I was asked in an interview the following question:

In an array of randomly generated booleans, such as : T F T T F F F T F F F F T

Write an algorithm to determine which false values to change to true, to maximize the largest continuous chunk of trues. In the above example, suppose that k = 3. One of the solutions would be:

```
T F T T T* T* T* T F F F F T
```

Where T* denotes a value that has been changed.

Besides simple bruteforce, one of the methods I came up with was to find the largest continuous chunk of False values, and compare it with k. If it is less, then we replace the entire chunk with True and continue with the 'k' that is remaining. However, it turns out this method didn't always guarantee the correct answer.

Another more complicated method I thought of is this: for every chunk of falses inbetween chunks of trues, compute how big of a chunk can be built by flipping the falses inbetween the trues. Then it comes down to selecting the best combination of chunks inbetween trues to flip.

What is the optimal algorithm for this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Find the largest range that contains k false values.  You can do this in linear time by keeping a running window.

Comment: Suppose k=3 and we have the following array: T F F F T F F F F F T T T T T T - then the algorithm would choose the first 3 false, instead of the last 3 false since 5 false is greater than 3. However, that is not the optimal solution since it's better to change the last 3 False to True, for a continuous chunk of 9 trues

Comment: @DrC: the range including the last three *false* as well as the *true*s up to the end looks optimal - I'd just word it *no more than k* to cover cases with fewer than *k false*s.

Comment: What happens if the most optimal solution requires the k flipped values to be separated rather than together. For example suppose k = 3

T T F T F F T T T F T T T T T F F F F F F T F 
We would flip  
T T __T__ T __T T__ T T T F T T T T T F F F F F F T F
In this case, simply finding the largest range that contains k false values wouldn't work

Comment: @Ryan implicit in the answer is that "range" includes the zero to two blocks of `T`s that may surround the `k` `F`s.

Answer (score 1):

You really can do this with a sliding window. I actually think that even though conceptually it's not a difficult problem, it is tricky to get the indexing right for the edge cases especially with the pressure of an interview.

Here's one way to do it:

Set two index variable to zero (`start` and `end`). Scan ahead incrementing `end` to right before the k+1 'F' (or the end of the array) putting the indexes of the 'F's in an array. This is your initial best guess and location of the 'F's.

Increment `end` to the next 'F', and move `start` to the next index in your array of F locations. Test if it's longer and repeat. You can keep track of the best `start` which will be the initial 'F' you'll need to change.

It's a little easier to show an example than explain, but it's basically a moving window while keeping track of the best run and best initial 'F' to change. Here's a quick and dirty JS implementation:

```js
function findBestFlips(k, arr) {
  let start, end, max, best_start, n;
  start = end = max = best_start_index = n = 0;

  let fs = [];

  for (end = 0; end <= arr.length; end++) {
    if (arr[end] == 0) {
      fs.push(end)
      if (fs.length <= k + 1) {
        max = end; // set initial max from start of array to right before (k+1)th false value 
        continue // fill up fs with k+1  values if possible
      }
      if (max < (end - (fs[start] + 1))) {
        max = end - (fs[start] + 1)
        best_start_index = start + 1
      }
      start++
    }
  }

  /* The above while loop stopped with potentially more ‘T’s at the end of the array.
     push on to the end of the array */

  if (max < arr.length - (fs[start] + 1)) {
    max = arr.length - (fs[start] + 1)
    best_start_index = start + 1
  }

  /* fs should have the index of all the false values
     best_start through  k + best_start_index are the indexes we need to change
     to get the best_run */
  if (fs.length <= k) max = arr.length
  return {
    flip_indexes: fs.slice(best_start_index, k + best_start_index),
    best_run: max
  }
}
let arr = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
let k = 3;

console.log(findBestFlips(k, arr))

// edge cases
arr = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
k = 3;
console.log(findBestFlips(k, arr))

arr = [0, 0, 0]
k = 3;
console.log(findBestFlips(k, arr))

arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
k = 3;
console.log(findBestFlips(k, arr))
```